# Mathematical YouTube channels?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list, online-resources

So I'm wondering if anybody knows any good math/science related YouTube channels? As for the math channels, I'm currently subscribed to Numberphile, and that is about it. I know few other channels, only ViHart actually (combining math and art). As for science-related channels, there are a lot more, like MinutePhysics, Veritasium and (sometimes) VSauce.

Does anyone got some other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you labeled Vsauce/Veritasium/MinutePhysics, I'm guessing you want interesting math channel. Numberphile is one I can think of.

Comment: [Art of the problem](https://www.youtube.com/user/ArtOfTheProblem) is a good one.  [Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCX6b17PVsYBQ0ip5gyeme-Q) is a good one for a surprising variety of subjects.

Comment: Also, [singingbanana](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMpizQXRt817D0qpBQZ2TlA) is the youtube name for James Grime, who periodically appears on Numberphile; he has a lot of interesting videos on his own (the roadway problem is a good one to look for).  [Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9-y-6csu5WGm29I7JiwpnA) has a good video on the very rough basics of linear algebra and graphical data-structures.

Comment: There are a lot of channels connected with numberphile as they are filmed by the [same person](http://periodicvideos.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/here-are-my-channels.html).

Comment: Great! Thanks for the suggestions. I've looked up Art of the problem, and they really tackle some interesting concepts!

Comment: Good channels, or just entertaining ones?  If you want to learn something, such as linear algebra, then I suggest the search phrase $$\text{"Linear Algebra" Lecture, playlist}$$ and you can find the actual good stuff, like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZK3O402wf1c&list=PLE7DDD91010BC51F8 .  I'm currently going through a lecture series on aeronautics, it's a great way to learn things.

Comment: Do not subscribe to Numberphile if you truly want to learn mathematics. They teach a lot of nonsense rather than real mathematics. 3Blue1Brown is excellent, and they **haven't** stopped making videos.

Answer (score 19):

I recommend [3Blue1Brown's Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw).
For an example, see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyW5z-M2yzw).

Also [The Mathologer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1_uAIS3r8Vu6JjXWvastJg)

EDIT: I'd also like to add a newer channel [PBS Infinite Series](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCs4aHmggTfFrpkPcWSaBN9g) (EDIT2: Unfortunately they already stopped making videos.)

Comment: I updated it, I hope this clears any possible confusion.

Answer (score 6):

You might wanna check out [Mathologer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1_uAIS3r8Vu6JjXWvastJg).

Comment: He is perhaps - the best of the ones mentioned. Most of the others just talk and expect you to see it passively, ML actually expects you to do something.

Answer (score 6):

There are so many great maths channels. I was planning to set up my own channel at some point but its a work in progress. The top 6 I would recommend would be: (in no particular order)

1. [3Blue1Brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw)
2. [Standupmaths](https://www.youtube.com/user/standupmaths)
3. [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/user/numberphile)
4. [Singingbanana](https://www.youtube.com/user/singingbanana)
5. [Mathologer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1_uAIS3r8Vu6JjXWvastJg)
6. [blackpenredpen](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_SvYP0k05UKiJ_2ndB02IA)

Answer (score 3):

I like [singingbanana](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCMpizQXRt817D0qpBQZ2TlA), James Grime's channel. I especially liked his videos

- [Building Houses Problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YMkziQhJkmM)
- [Building Houses Solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5q-MzS-lPE)

Answer (score 2):

I like the channel [Tipping Point Math](https://www.youtube.com/user/TippingPointMath). Lots of interesting math made by a math professor.

Answer (score 2):

[Flammable Maths](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCtAIs1VCQrymlAnw3mGonhw)

is sometimes entertaining with good integrals that are sometimes challanging.

Answer (score 1):

My channel is middle school math traps on youtube and maybe 6th graders and up will find it helpful .

Thank you!

[middle school math traps](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCj-RHh4Fm9mJqL6uCMAQl6Q)

Answer (score 1):

If you want high school maths then the channel Eddie Woo is a great one.
Also, the channel ViHart is great for random mathematics. Welch Labs is also a great channel.

Comment: Eddie Woo teaches wrongly and doesn't care at all about fixing his mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

**Channels which can be really helpful in understanding mathematics better are -**

*3Blue1Brown Lockdown Math playlist-*
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDP5CVelJJ1bNDouqrAhVPev

*Simon Pampena on Numberphile -*
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLt5AfwLFPxWJm_xYEUbnOi0foDNp2dwEX

*3Blue1Brown -* https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw

*Mathologer -* https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1_uAIS3r8Vu6JjXWvastJg

**Just for more content -**

*Numberphile-*
https://www.youtube.com/user/numberphile

*Think Twice -*
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC9yt3wz-6j19RwD5m5f6HSg

Answer (score 0):

Depending in what you're looking for, you might be interested in a math series, The Art of Math: A No B.S. Guide, that I'm making on youtube. It's primarily meant to reach students that are, by today's American standards, roughly ages 10-18, or 5th-12th grade.  Here's a link to the playlist so you can follow along the series in order: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLtMJUI0rs4e5BLanthvCYmW5EeFs6wY3z

I welcome feedback! Enjoy!